# close connection elasticsearch, is it necessary?

Tags: scala, api, elasticsearch, spray

im create a API using scala and library Spray.IO. my API, search into elasticsearch.

my questions is also related with [question](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4438).

```
var klt:TransportClient = EsClient_08012017.klien1
var arg = Array(JsObject(Map("id"->JsString("-1"), "item" -> JsString("-1"), "score"-> JsString("-1"))))

if(cariIndex(namaIndexCari)==true && cariIndex(namaIndexCari+"_2")==true)
{
  if(hitungJumlahIndex(namaIndexCari) > hitungJumlahIndex(namaIndexCari+"_2"))
  {
    val ar = ambilRekomendasi(idPenggunaCari, namaTipeCari, namaIndexCari, jumlah, false)
    val atd = acakTanpaDuplikat(ar)
    arg = parsingJsObject(atd)
  }

  else
  {
    val ar = ambilRekomendasi(idPenggunaCari, namaTipeCari, namaIndexCari+"_2", jumlah, false)
    val atd = acakTanpaDuplikat(ar)
    arg = parsingJsObject(atd)
  }
}

else
{
  val ar = ambilRekomendasi(idPenggunaCari, namaTipeCari, namaIndexCari, jumlah, false)
  val atd = acakTanpaDuplikat(ar)
  arg = parsingJsObject(atd)
}
klt.close()
arg
```

for 1st time, hit API its fine. but, the 2nd hit API im get some error

```
None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

what i want to achieve are, each of hit API its also like close connection to ES and open connection. but, the reference link said "it's okay without close connections". thanks for help, or link, or reference!

Answer (score 0):

Never close it unless you are closing your application

Comment: why i cannot close my connection? im newbie here, hehe
thanks